# Derivation of the contravariant basis vectors for the tangential place of a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, dual-spaces, outer-product

We know that (see for example "Vector and Geometric Calculus" by Alan Macdonald, pp. 74, problem 5.4.2) given the covariant basis vectors $\mathbf{b}_1$ and $\mathbf{b}_2$ of the tangential plane $T_P$ of a surface $S$ (defined in $\mathbb{R}^3$) the contravariant basis vectors $\mathbf{b}^1$, $\mathbf{b}^2$ are given by,
\begin{equation} \label{one}
\mathbf{b}^1 = \frac{\mathbf{b}_2\times(\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2)}{|\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2|^2}  \tag{1.1}
\end{equation}
and,
\begin{equation}  \label{two}
\mathbf{b}^2 = -\frac{\mathbf{b}_1\times(\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2)}{|\mathbf{b}_1 \times \mathbf{b}_2|^2}  \tag{1.2}
\end{equation}
where I have replaced the geometric and outer products with cross products. Given a parametrization,
\begin{equation}
S \; : \; x^i=x^i(u^1,u^2) \quad , \quad \text{for $i=1,2,3$}
\end{equation}
then $\mathbf{b}_a=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^a}\rvert_P$ where $a=1,2$.

We also know that the contravariant basis vectors are given by,
\begin{equation}  \label{three}
\mathbf{b}^a = \mathbf{\nabla} u^a  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
(see "Introduction to Differential Geometry of Space Curves and Surfaces", Taha Sochi, p.96, (181)) where $\mathbf{\nabla}=\partial/\partial x^i$.

Is there a way to derive (\ref{one}), (\ref{two}) from (\ref{three})? Given a specific parametrization of the surface (see below) how can we derive the contravariant basis vectors using (\ref{three}) instead of (\ref{one}),(\ref{two})?
\begin{align}
    x^1 & = \cos\theta u^1 - \sin\theta u^2 \\
    x^2 & = \sin\theta u^1 + \cos\theta u^2 \\
    x^3 & = U + A \exp\left(-\frac{(u^1)^2+(u^2)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: what is $\mathbf b_1\!\times\mathbf b_2$?

Comment: The cross product of the two basis vectors